# JSON message encoding

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, json.net

Why does the JSON message I receive from a web service (unknown platform) contains double `""` and `\u0142`? For example:

```
{""message"":""Nieprawid\u0142owy format""}
```

When I serialise my own object into a JSON message using json.net the resulting message contains only single `"`.

Finally, how to parse such a JSON message to get rid of `""` and convert `\u0142` to Unicode without deserializing the whole message into an object - just to get a proper JSON message text?

Comment: Single and double quotes are interchangeable (in pairs) in javascript. Maybe they used double quotes because strings containing a single quote (apostrophe) are more common than strings containing double quotes.

Comment: `\u...` encoding with JSON.NET is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8785912/3936440, might be helpful.

Comment: @itsme86 - Thanks for explanation. However I mean a different case - two consecutive double quotes as illustrated by example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find the answer, however parsing (deserializing) JSON message with json.net results with proper data. So I gave up with getting the raw message.